# Setting Font attributes in Beamer

Tags: fonts, beamer

I have to make slides under some given restrictions for a presentation.  I am thinking of using beamer, even though I have not used it before.  One of the given restrictions is that a title has to be in Arial, 44 pt size, and bold.  After reading the manual I came up with the following experimental code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamerfont*{titlefont}{size*={44pt}{24pt}, family={\fontfamily{phv}}, series=\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\usebeamerfont*{titlefont}
Titles 44 pt and bold
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output is in Arial and bold, however, the size seems much larger than 44pt.  What seems to be the problem?  Is there anther way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the font size has to be `44pt`?

Comment: Note that on viewing in Adobe Reader, the default zoom is fit page, implying a zoom level > 100%. Also, the font size used is actually *less than* `44pt` (it's `42.99pt`), since no `44pt` in `phv` exist; LaTeX does a substitution here. To see what `44pt` looks like, add `\rule{1pt}{44pt}` before the title, and you'll see that your title is smaller than the `44pt` rule.

Comment: Note that `Arial` is a clone of `Helvetica`, but not completely identical to it. (Most people probably would be hard-pressed to tell them apart, except maybe when shown some letters such as `R`, `G`, and `a`.) If the organization where you're giving the presentation is a stickler about fonts, you may be asked to use a "real" `Arial` rather than `Helvetica`. (I know: there's no accounting for tastes...) If that happens, you may want to take a look at the URW Arial package, available at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/arial.

Comment: Presentation are *zoomed*. A requirement of an absolute font size doesn't make sense if you don't know to which frame size it relates. In beamer the frame size is quite small (128mm by 96mm), so that normal font sizes like 14pt look already quite large. See section 8.3. Frame and Margin Sizes of the documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks.  I did not know about the beamer frame size.  They are talking about a regular (8inx11in) landscape page.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: The font size has to be 44pt. But, now knowing the frame size, I may have to find the correct pt size proportional to the frame size, i.e., some dilation with a less than 1 scale factor is required. or take another route.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks.  They insist that it has to be sanserif Arial or Tahoma.

Comment: @Werner: I calculated the scale factor to be 5/11.  That is, instead of 44 pt, I have to use 20 pt to have the desired effect. However, as you pointed out the rule is longer than the beginning T.

Comment: To match the ruler, I have to use 28pt.  That does not make sense.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: OK.  I have got everything to work as required.  It was your comment that lead to the resolution.  So, you should post it as an answer so that I can accept it and give closure to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presentation are *zoomed*. A requirement of an absolute font size doesn't make sense if you don't know to which frame size it relates. In beamer the frame size is quite small (128mm by 96mm), so that normal font sizes like 14pt look already quite large. See section 8.3. Frame and Margin Sizes of the documentation.